# Adding input data from a textbox to a confirmation message in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, null, confirmation

I am trying to get a confirmation box to display my input data from a textbox, but instead of whatever I put in, the confirmation box displays "null" where the input is supposed to be. Please help. I tried adding .val() to name in the confirmation box, but no luck. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jr3Nn/1/)

HTML:

```
First Name: <input type="text" id="namebox">
<input type="submit" id="submitbutton" onClick="confirmFunc()">
```

JS:

```
function confirmFunc() {
    var name = document.getElementById("#namebox");
    confirm("Please confirm that the following name is correct: " +name);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
function confirmFunc() {
var name = document.getElementById("namebox").value;
confirm("Please confirm that the following name is correct: " +name);
};
```

Comment: This works, thanks. I will accept your answer as soon as Stack Overflow lets me.